# Scripting TFS Command Line for Get Latest Version, Check Out and Check in, programmatically

Tags: tfs, scripting, checkin, vcs-checkout, getlatest

I use WinXP, VS 2008 and Team Explorer to connect to Team Foundation Server.

I need to script (e.g. BAT file script) the following:

- Get latest version of folder in Team Project.
- Check out files of folder in Team Project.
- Check in files of folder in Team Project.

My TFSProject is `$/Arquitectura/Main/`, mapped to the path `C:\TFS\Arquitectura`

Does anyone have any sample code or suggestions?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Use tf.exe in the command line.

In the following examples, the `%PathToIde%` is usually on a path like this: `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE`, or on Windows x64: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` (depending on Visual Studio version and installation settings).

**Example for get:**

```
cd C:\TFS\Arquitectura
"%PathToIde%\TF.exe" get $/Arquitectura/Main /recursive
```

**Example for checkout:**

```
cd C:\TFS\Arquitectura
"%PathToIde%\TF.exe" checkout $/Arquitectura/Main /recursive
```

**Example for checkin:**

```
cd C:\TFS\Arquitectura
"%PathToIde%\TF.exe" checkin $/Arquitectura/Main /recursive
```

See for more information on the [tf commandline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=VS.90).aspx).

Comment: "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get $/Project /recursive for VS 2010 on Win x64. Thanks for input, very useful!

Comment: "%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\TF.exe" get $/PROJECT_NAME /recursive for VS2013

Comment: Sorry for digging up this old post, but i have a question: When working with different local TFS workspaces, where do i specify the workspace to use? Or is this implied by the current working directory?

Answer (score 13):

Update for VS2017

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe'

Comment: Better comment than answer.

Comment: Thanks for professional "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"

Answer (score 6):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" get "$/ProjectName/Main" /force /recursive

Comment: @Neolisk Why are you suggesting the use of `/force` in this standard case?

Answer (score 4):

get up to date code  for Windows 7 64bit

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get /recursive
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following piece of code in Powershell on Windows 10 64-bit and it worked for me:

cd C:\MyWorkspace
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get $/TFSFolderPath /recursive

Please note that the second line starts with an Ampersand (&), my code doesn't work without it, don't know the reason for it though.

Comment: [Found explanation for the & Call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html).  Surrounding a command with quotes will make PowerShell treat it as a string, so in addition to quotes, use the & call operator to force PowerShell to treat the string as a command to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Visual Studio 2022**

Create a Batch file for taking the latest version from TFS.
Save this file with `.bat` extension

**TakeLatest.bat**

```
@echo off
title Project Builder
echo Taking Latest of All Projects which are listed here

cd /d %~dp0

call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe" get /recursive

pause
```

Note: `cd  /d` is your project folder location drive

**For Visual Studio 2019**

Update with this line into batch file ,

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe" get /recursive
```