# VSTS / TFVC cli for oracle developer

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am an oracle database developer. My organization is using VSTS repos for code storage. For people who are working with Visual studio, it is easy to check in codes. But for Db people, we always have to check-in the code manually by dragging in.

is there any way to connect to vsts repos source control with oracle tool? We are using TFVC as our version control (and not GIT).

Comment: The first question here is, why is git not present? If there's a reason for that, it probably limits other tools too.

Comment: @JamesZ I think project was created like that.. I saw and now trying to look for options that can fit there.. I know its very annoying to simply drag and drop files..

Comment: Do you mean to say that the project uses TFVC insted of git?

Comment: @JamesZ yes, we are just using TFVC. There is no git

Comment: You should use tf command line instead of VSTS CLI or Azure DevOps CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, seems you are using TFVC as your source control. Assuming you are working on windows platform, [check in command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=azure-devops) should be the one you are looking for.

> In the following examples, the `%PathToIde%` is usually on a path like
>   this: `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE`, or on
>   Windows x64: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE` (depending on Visual Studio version and installation settings).
>
> **Example for get:**
>
> ```
> cd C:\TFS\Arquitectura
>
> "%PathToIde%\TF.exe" get $/Arquitectura/Main /recursive
> ```
>
> **Example for checkout:**
>
> ```
> cd C:\TFS\Arquitectura
>
> "%PathToIde%\TF.exe" checkout $/Arquitectura/Main /recursive
> ```
>
> **Example for checkin:**
>
> ```
> cd C:\TFS\Arquitectura
>
> "%PathToIde%\TF.exe" checkin $/Arquitectura/Main /recursive
> ```
>
> *[Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762812/scripting-tfs-command-line-for-get-latest-version-check-out-and-check-in-progr)*

If you are working on Linux, take a look at this blog-- [Team Foundation Version Control and the Linux Command Line](https://holymonkey.com/team-foundation-version-control-client-in-linux.html)

Comment: do I need visual studios installed for using tf.exe ? or I can download it from somewhere ? I don't have visual studios installed

Comment: @BiswajitBuragohain Visual Studio is not necessary. You need to install **Team Explorer**, it's best to install the version of Team Explorer that matches the version of TFS you are using e.g. if you're using Azure DevOps 2019 then install Team Explorer 2019. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503858/how-to-get-tf-exe-tfs-command-line-client

Comment: Hey @PatrickLu-MSFT thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should look at the TF.exe CLI. This CLI lets you pretty much do everything that you can in the VS GUI.

Here's a link to the Microsoft doc's for TF, [Use Team Foundation version control commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I tried VSTS cli and Azure Cli, didn't worked for me. I am still unable to perform push request